# How insert, update and delete data with a view

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to get, update, delete and insert data in a view. So far I can get and update data from the view. I use Entity Framework Core 2.1 version.

This is the view model:

```
public partial class vwVacation: IEntity
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; private set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; private set; }
        public string EmployeeSurName { get; private set; }        
        public string EmployeeOccupation { get; private set; }
        public string EmployeePhone { get; private set; }
        public string EmployeeEmail { get; private set; }
        public int HeadQuartersId { get; private set; }
        public string HeadQuartersName { get; private set; }
        public string HeadQuartersCode { get; private set; }
        public int VacationId { get; set; }
        public int VacationTypeId { get; set; }
        public string VacationType{ get; private set; }
        [Column("HistoryId")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public int VacationDaysTake{ get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code that I write in the entity context:

```
 public virtual DbSet<vwVacation> vwVacation{ get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
modelBuilder.Entity<vwVacation>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

                entity.Property(e => e.EndDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.StartDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsApproved)
                   .HasColumnType("bit")
                   .HasDefaultValueSql("('0')");             

                entity.ToTable("vwVacation");

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeId)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;                 

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeName)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeSurName)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeOccupation)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeePhone)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeEmail)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.HeadQuartersId)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.HeadQuartersName)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;

                entity.Property(e => e.HeadQuartersCode)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;             

                entity.Property(e => e.VacationType)
                 .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;
            });
        }
```

What I need to do to insert data in my view and entity framework know which column are for insert and which column are ReadOnly ?

Comment: If you do want to perform DML operations against a `VIEW`, then is must be a "simple" view; only returns data from a single table with no aggragatiom, etc. If it isn't a simple `VIEW`, you'll need to implement `INSERT OF` triggers.

Comment: Larnu meant "instead of " triggers.